Reading string from csv into struct in c
i want to read this type of csv file with this column names.
imdb_id,movie_id,title,plot,type,rated,year,released_at,added_at,runtime,genre,director,writer,actors,language,country,awards,imdb_rating,imdb_votes

and this are the rows.
0,tt0147800,10 Things I Hate About You,"A pretty, popular teenager can't go out on a date until her ill-tempered older sister does.",movie,PG-13,1999,31 Mar 1999,"November 12, 2019",97 min,"Comedy, Drama, Romance",Gil Junger,"Karen McCullah, Kirsten Smith","Heath Ledger, Julia Stiles, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Larisa Oleynik","English, French",USA,2 wins & 13 nominations.,7.3,"283,945"
2,tt0115433,101 Dalmatians,"An evil high-fashion designer plots to steal Dalmatian puppies in order to make an extravagant fur coat, but instead creates an extravagant mess.",movie,G,1996,27 Nov 1996,"November 12, 2019",103 min,"Adventure, Comedy, Crime, Family",Stephen Herek,"Dodie Smith (novel), John Hughes (screenplay)","Glenn Close, Jeff Daniels, Joely Richardson, Joan Plowright","English, Spanish","USA, UK",Nominated for 1 Golden Globe. Another 3 wins & 9 nominations.,5.7,"97,785"

and this is my whole code reading this.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 2048

char *strdup(const char *str);

typedef struct{

    int imdb_id;
    char *movie_id;
    char *title;
    char *plot;
    char *type;
    char *rated;
    int year;
    char *released_at;
    char *added_at;
    char *runtime;
    char *genre;
    char *director;
    char *writer;
    char *coma;
    char *actors;
    char *coma2;
    char *language;
    char *coma3;
    char *country;
    char *awards;
    float imdb_rating;
    char *imdb_votes;


} order;

order or[MAX];

int leni;

int read_txt(char *file);

void getData(char *buff);

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){


    if ( argc < 2)
    {
        printf("No hay suficiente argumentos\n");
        return 1;
    }


    read_txt(argv[1]);



    return 0;

}

int read_txt(char *file){


    FILE *f=fopen(file,"r");

    if ( f == NULL)
    {
        printf("El archivo esta vacio\n");
        return 1;
    }

    order* o;
    char buff[1024];
    char* delimiter = ",\"";
    while (fgets(buff, MAX, f) != NULL)
    {
        o = (order *)malloc(sizeof(order));

        o->imdb_id = atoi(strtok(buff, ",\""));
        o->movie_id = strdup(strtok(NULL, delimiter));
        o->title = strdup(strtok(NULL, delimiter));
        o->plot = strdup(strtok(NULL, "\""));
        o->type = strdup(strtok(NULL, delimiter));
        o->rated = strdup(strtok(NULL, delimiter));
        o->year = atoi(strtok(NULL, delimiter));
        o->released_at=strdup(strtok(NULL, delimiter));
        o->added_at=strdup(strtok(NULL, "\""));
        o->runtime=strdup(strtok(NULL, delimiter));
        o->genre=strdup(strtok(NULL, "\""));
        o->director=strdup(strtok(NULL, delimiter));
        o->writer=strdup(strtok(NULL, "\""));
        o->coma=strdup(strtok(NULL, "\""));
        o->actors=strdup(strtok(NULL, "\""));
        o->coma2=strdup(strtok(NULL, "\""));
        o->language=strdup(strtok(NULL, "\""));
        o->country=strdup(strtok(NULL, delimiter));

        or[leni++] = *o;
     }
     for ( int l = 0;l<leni;l++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", or[l].country);
        }

     fclose(f);

     return 0;

}


char *strdup(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *dup = malloc(len);
    if (dup != 0)
        memmove(dup, str, len);  
    return(dup);
}

My question is i need a way to read the country column.
When i print this column this is my output.
USA
USA

And the expected output for this column is
USA
USA, UK

The problem is in the delimiter part but i don't know how to put a delimiter in strtok that changes for two rows.
In the first row the country column is USA, but in the second row for the country column is "USA, UK".
And the quotes are the problem.

I wrote an answer for this problem a few days ago here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78264711/how-to-read-an-csv-file-into-an-struct-and-putting-it-inside-an-array/78265171#78265171

It is seldom correct to use strtok() for CSV files because it destroys information about the delimiters — it writes null bytes over the delimiters.

MAX is used as the dimension of or[]. It is (incorrectly) used again in the fgets() function call.

memmove() will work, but is a $10 function being used for a $0.50 operation.

o = (order*)malloc(sizeof(order)); allocates a heap block each iteration. or[leni++] = *o; copies bytes to an element of a global array of structs. The allocated heap block is never free()'d causing a memory leak. (PS: It's unnecessary and a risky practice to cast the void * pointer returned from malloc().)

OP Code Review (repeated from comments below OP's Q)

MAX is used as the dimension of or[]. It is (incorrectly) used again in the fgets() function call.
memmove() will work, but is a $10 function being used for a $0.50 operation.
o = (order*)malloc(sizeof(order)); allocates a heap block each iteration. or[leni++] = *o; copies bytes to an element of a global array of structs. The allocated heap block is never free()'d causing a memory leak.
It's unnecessary and a risky practice to cast the void * pointer returned from malloc().


@AllanWind has already provided a tour de force answer worthy of praise.
The following is a "good enough" demonstration of another method of teasing apart the fields from lines of CSV data. Its purpose is merely to minimally "tease apart" those fields, and to remove leading and trailing double quote characters from each. (A small extension to reduce multiple pairs of double quote characters to single instances has been left as an exercise.)
To focus on the principle issue, the OP's strings have been put into a "compile-time" array of mutable strings, obviating the need for file access and line input that may only clutter this example's purpose. Further, a few of the OP's strings have been shortened while maintaining their "challenging" contents.
Once each field has been isolated, its contents are printed. Further processing of each field or collections of fields has been omitted.
The OP's question boils down to handling a particular field of source data that may-or-may-not be enclosed in double quote characters.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *unQuote( char *p ) {
    // presumes a field beginning with '"' will end with '"'
    if( *p == '"' ) {
        p[ strlen( p ) - 1 ] = '\0'; // suppress trailing '"'
        p += 1; // advance past leading '"'

        // TBD: compress possible (multiple?) instances of "" to only one "
    }

    return p;
}

char *nxt( char **pNxt ) { // isolate "next" field
    char *pOrg = *pNxt; // original location

    if( pOrg == NULL || *pOrg == '\0' ) return NULL; // end of fields

    int qCnt = 0; // quote counter
    // when qCnt is even, a comma is a separator
    // when qCnt is odd, a comma is an embedded comma (leave alone)

    char *cp = pOrg;
    for( ; *cp && ( *cp != ',' || qCnt%2 ); cp++ )
        qCnt += *cp == '"';

    if( *cp == '\0' )
        *pNxt = NULL; // last field?
    else {
        *cp = '\0'; // terminate this field and...
        *pNxt = cp + 1; // remember where next one starts
    }

    return unQuote( pOrg ); // strip leading/trailing double quote if present
}

void process( char *pNxt ) { // process one CSV line
    int fCnt = 0; // field counter
    char *p;
    while( ( p = nxt( &pNxt ) ) != NULL )
        printf( "\t%2d - '%s'\n", fCnt++, p ); // show field content between ticks
}

int main( void ) {
    char *strs[] = {
        "0,tt0147800,10 Things I Hate About You,"
        "\"A pretty, popular teenager can't date until her tempered older sister does.\","
        "movie,PG-13,1999,31 Mar 1999,\"November 12, 2019\",97 min,"
        "\"Comedy, Drama, Romance\",Gil Junger,"
        "\"Karen McCullah, Kirsten Smith\",\"Heath Ledger, Julia Stiles, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Larisa Oleynik\","
        "\"English, French\",USA,2 wins & 13 nominations.,7.3,\"283,945\"",
        
        "2,tt0115433,101 Dalmatians,"
        "\"Evil designer steals puppies to make fur coat, but creates mess.\","
        "movie,G,1996,27 Nov 1996,\"November 12, 2019\",103 min,"
        "\"Adventure, Comedy, Crime, Family\",Stephen Herek,"
        "\"Dodie Smith (novel), John Hughes (screenplay)\",\"Glenn Close, Jeff Daniels, Joely Richardson, Joan Plowright\","
        "\"English, Spanish\",\"USA, UK\",Nominated for 1 Golden Globe. Another 3 wins & 9 nominations.,5.7,\"97,785\"",

        // challenging, including empty fields, even last field is empty
        "3,foobar,,,\"foo,bar\",here's more,,,",
    };

    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof strs/sizeof strs[0]; i++ ) {
        printf( "\n%lu - %-.60s\n" + !i, i, strs[i] ); // show truncated line contents

        process( strs[i] );
    }

    puts( "\nAll done" );

    return 0;
}

Testing shows multiple trailing empty fields are not handled well. There are several ways additional code could be added to accommodate lines ending with empty fields. Left as an exercise.
Output (note field 15. Both USA and USA, UK have been returned as desired.)
0 - 0,tt0147800,10 Things I Hate About You,"A pretty, popular te
         0 - '0'
         1 - 'tt0147800'
         2 - '10 Things I Hate About You'
         3 - 'A pretty, popular teenager can't date until her tempered older sister does.'
         4 - 'movie'
         5 - 'PG-13'
         6 - '1999'
         7 - '31 Mar 1999'
         8 - 'November 12, 2019'
         9 - '97 min'
        10 - 'Comedy, Drama, Romance'
        11 - 'Gil Junger'
        12 - 'Karen McCullah, Kirsten Smith'
        13 - 'Heath Ledger, Julia Stiles, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Larisa Oleynik'
        14 - 'English, French'
        15 - 'USA'
        16 - '2 wins & 13 nominations.'
        17 - '7.3'
        18 - '283,945'

1 - 2,tt0115433,101 Dalmatians,"Evil designer steals puppies to
         0 - '2'
         1 - 'tt0115433'
         2 - '101 Dalmatians'
         3 - 'Evil designer steals puppies to make fur coat, but creates mess.'
         4 - 'movie'
         5 - 'G'
         6 - '1996'
         7 - '27 Nov 1996'
         8 - 'November 12, 2019'
         9 - '103 min'
        10 - 'Adventure, Comedy, Crime, Family'
        11 - 'Stephen Herek'
        12 - 'Dodie Smith (novel), John Hughes (screenplay)'
        13 - 'Glenn Close, Jeff Daniels, Joely Richardson, Joan Plowright'
        14 - 'English, Spanish'
        15 - 'USA, UK'
        16 - 'Nominated for 1 Golden Globe. Another 3 wins & 9 nominations.'
        17 - '5.7'
        18 - '97,785'

2 - 3,foobar,,,"foo,bar",here's more,,,
         0 - '3'
         1 - 'foobar'
         2 - ''
         3 - ''
         4 - 'foo,bar'
         5 - 'here's more'
         6 - ''
         7 - '' // Needs more work. Multiple empty trailing fields.

All done


It must be acknowledged that this code is "less efficient" than alternatives that do not make these multiple passes over the same regions data being processed. Efficiency is a noble objective... as is simplicity. The designer/coder should keep (at least these) two things in mind.

Others, perhaps with less skill or aptitude, may have to maintain/adapt the code in the future. Would such an individual be grateful to the author of super-clever code, or not?
If 'n' lines of working (simplistic) code achieves the same outcome as, perhaps, '4n' lines of code that processes with greater efficiency, and the latter reduces execution time from, say, 0.9 seconds to 0.4 seconds for a program run, perhaps, a few times every day, week or month, is it worth investing hours coding, debugging & supporting the more efficient version?



My question is i need a way to read the country column.

All columns are equal:

you need to have quotes around fields that possibly have delimiters or white-space inside. Sometimes fields can include even include \n. It is common for CSV that handle for example paragraphs of text.
pairs of quotes can be used to insert " in fields
quoting is optional
you need to care for spaces at the start, at the end or in the middle of fields
in general there is an ESCAPE symbol also, that protects a single char
many times there are ways to select the fields to import, by number


The problem is in the delimiter part but i don't know how to put a delimiter in strtok that changes for two rows.
In the first row the country column is USA, but in the second row for the country column is "USA, UK".
And the quotes are the problem.

You are not programming for the rows you have, "two rows" or 200,000 rows. You are programming against an established format of decades ago.
The real source of trouble is srtok here. And some problems with he code itself and the csv format interpretation itself.

Any field can be quoted
Some fields MUST be quoted
all lines MUST have the same number of delimiters

it is way easier to write a state machine
You can go with strdup, strtok. You can use fscanf, but a state machine is simpler.
As an example, the code below parses any CSV line and returns the number of fields, using a minimalistic state machine: one with 2 states. Yes, it works with your file as it is. A complete example follows
size_t so_count_fields(
  char* const line, char delim, char quote)
{
  char*  p_in     = line;
  char   state    = ST_IN;
  size_t n_fields = 0;

  if (line == NULL) return 0;
  while (*p_in != 0)
  {
      switch (state)
      {
          case ST_IN:
              if (*p_in == SYMB_NEWLINE)
                  return ++n_fields;
              if (*p_in == quote)
              {
                  state = ST_QUOTE;
                  ++p_in;
                  break;
              };
              if (*p_in == delim)
              {
                  ++p_in;
                  ++n_fields;
                  state = ST_IN;
                  break;
              };
              ++p_in;
              break;
          case ST_QUOTE:
              if (*p_in == SYMB_NEWLINE)
              {  // unbalanced quote
                  fprintf(
                      stderr,
                      "so_count_fields(): unbalanced "
                      "quotes\n");
                  return 0;
              }
              if (*p_in == quote)
              {
                  p_in++;
                  state = ST_IN;
                  break;
              };
              ++p_in;
              break;
          default:  // in a word
              fprintf(
                  stderr,
                  "so_count_fields(): invalid state: "
                  "%d\n",
                  state);
              return 0;
      };  // switch(state)
  };  // while()
  return ++n_fields;
}

Note that the header line is a line like any other, but you should keep this record apart. This line will be used in the whole program: those are the titles for every field, so you can have, in your case, a record described by an array, like char* record[19].
Avoid at any cost using field names in code: this is a pain and we can imagine that the header line is here for this very reason. You do not write code for a single use.
A record (line) can be seen as
typedef struct
{
    size_t limit;
    size_t size;
    char** field;
} Record;

A full CSV can be seen as as array of records, like
typedef struct
{
    size_t  inc_records;  // increment
    size_t  max_records;  // limits
    size_t  n_fields;     // # of fields
    size_t  size;         // counters
    char    delim;
    char    quote;
    char*** csv;  // the data
} CSV;            // a collection

using CSV "cells" like in a spreadsheet
This is the original file imported into Microsoft Excel using only the defaults:

Seeing a CSV file as a char*** thing brings this convenience: A line like
            printf(
                "\tField %llu/%llu [%s]:\n\n\t\t%s\n\n",
                1 + f, C->n_fields, C->csv[0][2],
                C->csv[1][2]);
        }

will show the movie title for the first data record, as in
       Field 3/19 [title]:

                10 Things I Hate About You

Note that fields are numbered from 0, as are also numbered the records, but record 0 has the field names.
an example viewing the csv as a csv[record][field] object
Note:

this is just a proof of concept. In particular, input data must be better filtered for invalid lines
many or all functions return error codes that are not treated at all
the name of the input file is expected at the command line. On the absence of that input.csv is used
the csv representation is extended in memory as needed. I used very low numbers just to force some extensions
quote and delimiter symbols are also defaulted to " and , but are just parameters to the parsing functions. Ideally should be given on the command line, following the input file name
X""""Y will translate to X"" as expected
I did no implemented ESCAPE because of laziness
Line terminator should also be a parameter. Assuming \n is restrictive, e.g. in case of processing text. Another case of laziness
I used Record for the fields and CSV for the CSV, but just as an example of both. There is no need for Record here. Data should go directly from input to CSV. But sometimes the Record abstraction is sufficiente, so I left both here as examples.

code for the example
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SYMB_NEWLINE '\n'
#define SYMB_NULL 0
#define SYMB_DELIM ','
#define SYMB_QUOTE '"'
#define SYMB_TAB '\t'
#define SYMB_SPACE 0x20

#define ST_IN 1
#define ST_QUOTE 2

#define MAX_SIZE 255

size_t so_count_fields(char* const, char, char);

typedef struct
{
    size_t  inc_records;  // increment
    size_t  max_records;  // limits
    size_t  n_fields;     // # of fields
    size_t  size;         // counters
    char    delim;
    char    quote;
    char*** csv;  // the data
} CSV;            // a collection

CSV* so_create_csv(size_t, size_t, size_t, char, char);
CSV* so_delete_csv(CSV* csv);
int  so_get_fields(FILE*, CSV*);
int  so_insert_csv(FILE*, CSV*);
int  so_show_csv(CSV*, const char*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* def_file_name = "input.csv";
    char        delim         = SYMB_DELIM;
    char        quote         = SYMB_QUOTE;

    char file_name[MAX_SIZE];
    if (argc > 3) quote = argv[3][0];
    if (argc > 2) quote = argv[2][0];
    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(file_name, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy(file_name, def_file_name);
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "loading \"%s\", delimiter is '%c' (0x%X), quote "
        "is "
        "'%c' (0x%X)\n",
        file_name, delim, delim, quote, quote);
    FILE* in = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    char  line[512] = {0};
    char* p         = fgets(line, sizeof(line), in);
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        fclose(in);
        return -1;
    }
    size_t n_fields =
        so_count_fields(p, SYMB_DELIM, SYMB_QUOTE);
    printf(
        "%llu fields counted in 1st record (headers)\n",
        n_fields);
    if (n_fields == 0) return 0;
    CSV* csv = so_create_csv(3, 3, n_fields, delim, quote);
    if (csv == NULL)
    {
        fclose(in);
        return -1;
    };
    rewind(in);  // re-reads header
    while (so_insert_csv(in, csv) == 0) {
    };  // consume input
    fclose(in);
    fprintf(
        stderr, "end of input. CSV has %llu records\n",
        csv->size);
    so_show_csv(csv, "\nCSV at the end:  ");
    so_delete_csv(csv);
    return 0;
};  // main()

size_t so_count_fields(
    char* const line, char delim, char quote)
{
    char*  p_in     = line;
    char   state    = ST_IN;
    size_t n_fields = 0;

    if (line == NULL) return 0;
    while (*p_in != 0)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case ST_IN:
                if (*p_in == SYMB_NEWLINE)
                    return ++n_fields;
                if (*p_in == quote)
                {
                    state = ST_QUOTE;
                    ++p_in;
                    break;
                };
                if (*p_in == delim)
                {
                    ++p_in;
                    ++n_fields;
                    state = ST_IN;
                    break;
                };
                ++p_in;
                break;
            case ST_QUOTE:
                if (*p_in == SYMB_NEWLINE)
                {  // unbalanced quote
                    fprintf(
                        stderr,
                        "so_count_fields(): unbalanced "
                        "quotes\n");
                    return 0;
                }
                if (*p_in == quote)
                {
                    p_in++;
                    state = ST_IN;
                    break;
                };
                ++p_in;
                break;
            default:  // in a word
                fprintf(
                    stderr,
                    "so_count_fields(): invalid state: "
                    "%d\n",
                    state);
                return 0;
        };  // switch(state)
    };  // while()
    return ++n_fields;
}

int so_get_fields(FILE* in, CSV* C)
{
    char   buffer[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
    char*  p_out            = buffer;
    size_t size             = 0;
    char   state            = ST_IN;
    size_t n_qf             = 0;  // size of quoted field
    size_t n_field          = 0;
    char** rcd = C->csv[C->size];  // at the end
    char   ch  = 0;

    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    if (C == NULL) return -2;
    // from 'in' insert a record into 'C'
    while (n_field != C->n_fields)
    {
        ch       = (char)fgetc(in);
        char err = 0;
        if (ch < 0) return -3;  // error or EOF
        switch (state)
        {
            case ST_IN:
                if ((ch == SYMB_NEWLINE) ||
                    (ch == SYMB_NULL))
                {
                    *p_out = 0;
                    // printf(
                    //     "==> field#%llu/%llu: [%s]\n",
                    //     n_field, C->n_fields, buffer);
                    //   save the field
                    rcd[n_field] =
                        malloc(1 + strlen(buffer));
                    if (rcd[n_field] == NULL)
                    {  // malloc failed
                        err = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    strcpy(rcd[n_field], buffer);
                    ++n_field;
                    break;
                };
                if ((ch == SYMB_TAB) || (ch == SYMB_SPACE))
                {
                    if (size != 0) *p_out++ = ch;
                    break;
                };
                if (ch == C->quote)
                {
                    state = ST_QUOTE;
                    n_qf  = 0;
                    break;
                };
                if (ch == C->delim)
                {
                    *p_out = 0;
                    // printf(
                    //     "==> field#%llu/%llu: [%s]\n",
                    //     n_field, C->n_fields, buffer);
                    //   save the field
                    rcd[n_field] =
                        malloc(1 + strlen(buffer));
                    if (rcd[n_field] == NULL)
                    {  // malloc failed
                        err = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    strcpy(rcd[n_field], buffer);
                    ++n_field;
                    p_out = buffer;
                    size  = 0;
                    if (n_field >= C->n_fields)
                    {
                        while ((ch = (char) fgetc(in)) >= 0)
                        {
                            if (ch == SYMB_NEWLINE) break;
                            if (ch == SYMB_NULL) break;
                        }; // flush rest of line
                    }
                    state = ST_IN;
                    break;
                };
                *p_out++ = ch;
                ++size;
                break;
            case ST_QUOTE:
                if (ch == SYMB_NEWLINE)
                {  // unbalanced quotes
                    fprintf(
                        stderr, "(Unbalanced quotes)\n");
                    err = 1;
                    break;
                }
                if (ch == C->quote)
                {
                    if (n_qf == 0)
                    {  // "" escaped quote in field
                        *p_out++ = '"';
                        n_qf     = 0;
                        ++size;
                    }
                    state = ST_IN;
                    break;
                };
                *p_out++ = ch;
                ++size;
                ++n_qf;
                break;
            default:  // in a word
                printf("Invalid state: %d\n", state);
                *p_out++ = 0;
                break;
        };  // switch(state)
        // on error must free all previous fields
        // for this record
        if (err != 0)
        {
            for (size_t f = 0; f < n_field; f += 1)
            {
                free(rcd[f]);
                rcd[f] = NULL;
            }
            break;
        }
    };  // while()
    return 0;
}

CSV* so_create_csv(
    size_t max_records, size_t inc_records, size_t n_fields,
    char delim, char quote)
{
    CSV* C = malloc(sizeof(CSV));
    if (C == NULL) return NULL;
    C->max_records = max_records;
    C->inc_records = inc_records;
    C->n_fields    = n_fields;
    C->size        = 0;
    C->delim       = delim;
    C->quote       = quote;
    C->csv         = malloc(max_records * sizeof(char***));
    if (C->csv == NULL)
    {
        free(C);
        return NULL;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < max_records; i += 1)
        C->csv[i] = NULL;
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "so_create_csv() size: %llu capacity: %llu "
        "increment: %llu\n",
        C->size, C->max_records, C->inc_records);
    return C;  // ok then...
}

CSV* so_delete_csv(CSV* csv)
{
    if (csv == NULL) return NULL;
    for (size_t r = 0; r < csv->size; r += 1)
    {  // delete record 'r'
        for (size_t f = 0; f < csv->n_fields; f += 1)
        {
            // delete field 'f'
            free(csv->csv[r][f]);
        }
        free(csv->csv[r]);
    };
    free(csv->csv);
    free(csv);
    return NULL;
}

///  from file 'in' gets a record into CSV `csv`
int so_insert_csv(FILE* in, CSV* csv)
{
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    if (csv == NULL) return -2;
    if (csv->size == csv->max_records)
    {  // extends size of csv
        size_t  new_size = csv->size + csv->inc_records;
        char*** ext =
            realloc(csv->csv, new_size * sizeof(char***));
        if (ext == NULL) return -3;  // could not extend
        csv->csv = ext;
        for (size_t i = csv->size; i < new_size; i += 1)
            csv->csv[i] = NULL;  // clears the new pointers
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "so_insert_csv(): capacity extended from "
            "%llu to %llu records\n",
            csv->max_records, new_size);
        csv->max_records = new_size;
    }
    csv->csv[csv->size] =
        (char**)malloc(csv->n_fields * sizeof(char*));
    if (csv->csv[csv->size] == NULL)
        return -4;  // could not alloc record
    if (so_get_fields(in, csv) == 0)
    {  // all set
        ++csv->size;
        return 0;
    }
    free(csv->csv[csv->size]);
    return -5;  // could not get full record;
}

int so_show_csv(CSV* C, const char* msg)
{
    if (C == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "%llu records [Max: %llu] %llu fields per "
        "record\n\n",
        C->size, C->max_records, C->n_fields);
    for (size_t r = 0; r < C->size; r += 1)
    {
        printf(
            "\n\n----------------------------------------"
            "\n[Record %llu/%llu]\n\n",
            1 + r, C->size);
        // show record 'r'
        for (size_t f = 0; f < C->n_fields; f += 1)
        {  // show field  'f'
            printf(
                "\tField %llu/%llu [%s]:\n\n\t\t[%s]\n\n",
                1 + f, C->n_fields, C->csv[0][f],
                C->csv[r][f]);
        }
    };
    printf("[ end of CSV, %llu records ]\n\n", C->size);
    return 0;
};

output
(Using only the first 10 fields of the 19 in header, just by editing the 1st line of the file and deleting the rest of the fields.)
Note that the input file, delimiter and quote symbols are sent on the command line. All can be omitted and default to this same values.


./ex3-0414 input.csv , ""
loading "input.csv", delimiter is ',' (0x2C), quote is '"' (0x22)
10 fields counted in 1st record (headers)
so_create_csv() size: 0 capacity: 3 increment: 3
so_insert_csv(): capacity extended from 3 to 6 records
end of input. CSV has 3 records

CSV at the end:  3 records [Max: 6] 10 fields per record



----------------------------------------
[Record 1/3]

        Field 1/10 [imdb_id]:

                [imdb_id]

        Field 2/10 [movie_id]:

                [movie_id]

        Field 3/10 [title]:

                [title]

        Field 4/10 [plot]:

                [plot]

        Field 5/10 [type]:

                [type]

        Field 6/10 [rated]:

                [rated]

        Field 7/10 [year]:

                [year]

        Field 8/10 [released_at]:

                [released_at]

        Field 9/10 [added_at]:

                [added_at]

        Field 10/10 [runtime]:

                [runtime]



----------------------------------------
[Record 2/3]

        Field 1/10 [imdb_id]:

                [0]

        Field 2/10 [movie_id]:

                [tt0147800]

        Field 3/10 [title]:

                [10 Things I Hate About You]

        Field 4/10 [plot]:

                [A pretty, popular teenager can't go out on a date until her ill-tempered older sister does.]

        Field 5/10 [type]:

                [movie]

        Field 6/10 [rated]:

                [PG-13]

        Field 7/10 [year]:

                [1999]

        Field 8/10 [released_at]:

                [31 Mar 1999]

        Field 9/10 [added_at]:

                [November 12, 2019]

        Field 10/10 [runtime]:

                [97 min]



----------------------------------------
[Record 3/3]

        Field 1/10 [imdb_id]:

                [2]

        Field 2/10 [movie_id]:

                [tt0115433]

        Field 3/10 [title]:

                [101 Dalmatians]

        Field 4/10 [plot]:

                [An evil high-fashion designer plots to steal Dalmatian puppies in order to make an extravagant fur coat, but instead creates an extravagant mess.]

        Field 5/10 [type]:

                [movie]

        Field 6/10 [rated]:

                [G]

        Field 7/10 [year]:

                [1996]

        Field 8/10 [released_at]:

                [27 Nov 1996]

        Field 9/10 [added_at]:

                [November 12, 2019]

        Field 10/10 [runtime]:

                [103 min]

[ end of CSV, 3 records ]

Not that memory is allocated as needed, and the unit of extension is a parameter on the creation of the csv.
using public datasets
Using this file from Census.org as population.csv, with 39 fields and 67 records
39 fields counted in 1st record (headers)

CSV at the end:  67 records [Max: 69] 39 fields per record



----------------------------------------
[Record 1/67]

    Field 1/39 [SUMLEV]:

        [SUMLEV]

    Field 2/39 [REGION]:

        [REGION]

    Field 3/39 [DIVISION]:

        [DIVISION]

    Field 4/39 [STATE]:

        [STATE]

    Field 5/39 [NAME]:

        [NAME]

    Field 6/39 [ESTIMATESBASE2020]:

        [ESTIMATESBASE2020]

    Field 7/39 [POPESTIMATE2020]:

        [POPESTIMATE2020]

    Field 8/39 [POPESTIMATE2021]:

        [POPESTIMATE2021]

    Field 9/39 [POPESTIMATE2022]:

        [POPESTIMATE2022]

    Field 10/39 [POPESTIMATE2023]:

        [POPESTIMATE2023]

    Field 11/39 [NPOPCHG_2020]:

        [NPOPCHG_2020]

    Field 12/39 [NPOPCHG_2021]:

        [NPOPCHG_2021]

    Field 13/39 [NPOPCHG_2022]:

        [NPOPCHG_2022]

    Field 14/39 [NPOPCHG_2023]:

        [NPOPCHG_2023]

    Field 15/39 [BIRTHS2020]:

        [BIRTHS2020]

    Field 16/39 [BIRTHS2021]:

        [BIRTHS2021]

    Field 17/39 [BIRTHS2022]:

        [BIRTHS2022]

    Field 18/39 [BIRTHS2023]:

        [BIRTHS2023]

    Field 19/39 [DEATHS2020]:

        [DEATHS2020]

    Field 20/39 [DEATHS2021]:

        [DEATHS2021]

    Field 21/39 [DEATHS2022]:

        [DEATHS2022]

    Field 22/39 [DEATHS2023]:

        [DEATHS2023]

    Field 23/39 [NATURALCHG2020]:

        [NATURALCHG2020]

    Field 24/39 [NATURALCHG2021]:

        [NATURALCHG2021]

    Field 25/39 [NATURALCHG2022]:

        [NATURALCHG2022]

    Field 26/39 [NATURALCHG2023]:

        [NATURALCHG2023]

    Field 27/39 [INTERNATIONALMIG2020]:

        [INTERNATIONALMIG2020]

    Field 28/39 [INTERNATIONALMIG2021]:

        [INTERNATIONALMIG2021]

    Field 29/39 [INTERNATIONALMIG2022]:

        [INTERNATIONALMIG2022]

    Field 30/39 [INTERNATIONALMIG2023]:

        [INTERNATIONALMIG2023]

    Field 31/39 [DOMESTICMIG2020]:

        [DOMESTICMIG2020]

    Field 32/39 [DOMESTICMIG2021]:

        [DOMESTICMIG2021]

    Field 33/39 [DOMESTICMIG2022]:

        [DOMESTICMIG2022]

    Field 34/39 [DOMESTICMIG2023]:

        [DOMESTICMIG2023]

    Field 35/39 [NETMIG2020]:

        [NETMIG2020]

    Field 36/39 [NETMIG2021]:

        [NETMIG2021]

    Field 37/39 [NETMIG2022]:

        [NETMIG2022]

    Field 38/39 [NETMIG2023]:

        [NETMIG2023]

    Field 39/39 [RESIDUAL2020]:

        [RESIDUAL2020]




----------------------------------------
[Record 2/67]

    Field 1/39 [SUMLEV]:

        [010]

    Field 2/39 [REGION]:

        [0]

// TRUNCATED.......................................................................



    Field 38/39 [NETMIG2023]:

        [1872]

    Field 39/39 [RESIDUAL2020]:

        [0]

[ end of CSV, 67 records ]


CSV in other applications
Google Cloud reads and writes CSV, like this way (from gcloud's documentation):
gcloud sql import csv INSTANCE URI --database=DATABASE, -d DATABASE 
   --table=TABLE [--async] [--columns=COLUMNS,[COLUMNS,…]]
   [--escape=ESCAPE] [--fields-terminated-by=FIELDS_TERMINATED_BY]
   [--lines-terminated-by=LINES_TERMINATED_BY]
   [--quote=QUOTE] [--user=USER] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]

MySQL database reads and writes CSV --- like Excel, or Google Sheets or Word or Oracle. An example (from MySQL's documentation):
mysql> SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/myndb_table.csv' > FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' > LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' > FROM myinnodbtable;

I did not implemented ESCAPE, and assumed '\n' as the line terminator, because I think it is not important here. I am writing this just to add that this is an established format, one that precedes internet and the IETF. There is an RFC-like document at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180. It is not complete, but it is useful.

Double quotes instead of [] in the output?

@AllanWind I used [field] because they seems good as, well, brackets to isolate content. Quotes here mess with the fact that every field can be quoted. And also in this example starting or ending quotes is an obvious first test cases in the state machine, as is ""field"  ;) Single quotes I considered but they are hard to read as delimiters (as far as my vision goes) and do not mix well with quoted fields: '"field"'

Sorry to know that, @Fe2O3. Hope you can sort this out best way. Cheers.
